# retrieve lisbox value in database using C#

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

actually iam using one listbox which have multiple values when user select a values the item in listbox are inserted database like "Abc,xyz,gkl" type now i want to retrieve this value from database in front of form and as Selected how can i do that here is the my code

```
ds = new DataSet();

              if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
              {


                  string[] arr_Electro_Therapy = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Electro_Therapy"].ToString().Trim().Split(',');
                  for (int i = 0; i < arr_Electro_Therapy.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < listBox1.Items.Count; k++)
                      {

                         if (listBox1.Items[k].Value.ToString().Trim() == arr_Electro_Therapy[i].ToString().Trim())
                          {

                              listBox1.Items[k].Selected = true;
                              hdSelected.Value = hdSelected.Value + ", " + listBox1.Items[k].;
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

Comment: do you need list like:
abc
xyz
gkl

Comment: can you share your code how your fetching data...